# Call server side dropdown list onchange function from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Is there any way to call server side drowndown list on change event to call from javascript..

```
<script>
     // change value of asp.net dropdown list
     // call onchange event of dropdown list
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding [Web Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ef803zd(v=vs.90).aspx) in you code behind which can be called through javascript or jQuery Ajax.